# jdbcTemplate.getDataSource() is always null in my unit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am new in writing junit test for spring boot applications. Could anybody help me to understand the situation?

I have a service I’d like to test:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    …    
    @Autowired
    public MyService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        …
    }
    @Async
    public SomeType myMethod(SomeDTO request) {
        DataSource dataSource = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        …
    }
    …
}
```

When I start my application and call service through REST API then my dataSource is correct and based on parameters from application.yml.

However, when I call it from my unit tests then `this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()` is always null.

Here my test classes:

**SpringBootTestApplication:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = TestConfigurator.class
)
public abstract class SpringBootTestApplication {
}
```

**MyServiceTest:**

```
    public class MyServiceTest  extends SpringBootTestApplication {

        @MockBean
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


        @Autowired
        @InjectMocks
        private MyService myService;

        @Test
        public void Test_1(){
            DataSource dataSource = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
myService.getSomething(dataSource, ...)
             …
        }


    }
```

Should I add something special to my TestConfigurator.class?

Comment: You need to mock your DataSource.

Comment: Could you show some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyServiceTest  extends 
    SpringBootTestApplication {

    @MockBean
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   private MyService myService;  

    @Before
     public void init(){
        myService = new MyService(this.jdbcTemplate);
   }

    @Test
    public void Test_1(){
       DataSource datasource = new DataSource());  
       when.jdbcTemplate.getDatasource()).thenReturn(datasource);
       myService.getSomething(dataSource, ...)
         …
    }


}
```

Comment: jdbcTemplate comes into Test_1() with jdbcTemplate.dataSource = null